# RS485 slew rate limiting remove need for termination

Tags: rs485, termination, slew-rate

In regards to the highlighted feature of "slew-rate limiting" RS485 ICs. It says in multiple brand datasheets that the slew-rate limiting helps with transmission errors when there is incorrect termination.

My questions are:

- Does the slew-rate limiting remove the need for termination completely? Only at certain baud rates or cable lengths? I know 9600 baud is pretty stable as-is; I am particular curious about and 38400 to 115200 baud.
- How would the RS485 bus behave if there is a mix of slew-rate limited ICs and non-limited ICs on the same bus? Does the slew-rate limiting only work if all RS485 ICs on the bus have this feature? Or can the feature be utilized locally on one PCB if it is the only one on the bus with a slew-rate limited IC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slew rate limiting helps, but does not remove the problem. It might allow a bus to run at low speeds without termination.

Short buses will most likely work without termination, but it is not recommended. So it all depends on how long or short your bus is, what is the slew rate, and what is the baud rate.

It will only work if all transmitters have slew rate limiting. If one transmitter only has slew rate limiting, it cannot do anything about the slew rate of other transmitters.

Answer (score 1):

slew rate limiting does not remove the need for termination.

The only way to prevent reflections from becoming a problem is to allow each bit to flood the bus and reflect back to the driver that's driving.

At 9600 baud this means a maximum bus length of about 9 kilometers,  at higher signalling rates the allowable bus length will be proportionally shorter: about 1500m at 115200 baud

At those distances hardening against lightning damage, and saving money by buying fibre instead of copper is probably a good move. so if you're running your RS485 at conventional UART data rates you probably don't need termination at all.